# Automate Tabbing though tabs in WXnotebook

Tags: python, wxwidgets, wxpython, wxnotebook

I have a WXnotebook that has different number of tabs depending on the amount of information that the program pulls. My goal is to take a screenshot of the information displayed by each tab and store those images. **Im having a problem with the program going through the tabs**. I was thinking maybe something like

```
         for i in range(numOfTabs):
            self.waferTab.ChangeSelection(i)
            time.sleep(3)
```

but this only shows me the last tab in the wxnotebook. If anybody knows anyway of getting this i'd really appreciate it.

**EDIT**

so I tried the following like suggested below but the GUI shows up but when it shows up It looks like it already iterated through the whole loop and displays the selection is the last tab I still cant see the screen actually going through the tabs

```
          for i in range(numOfTabs):
            self.waferTab.SetSelection(i)
            Refresh
            wx.SafeYield()
            time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: `ChangeSelection` is the right function to change the selected page in a wx.Notebook. Your problem likely is somewhere else, but you don't show enough code so as to search for it.

Comment: the other lines on my code just help display the information into the tabs. I want to show the first tab then after 3 seconds show the 2nd tab and so on

Comment: @JeffPernia, can you make a script sleep for 1 minute? Or instead of looping just call `self.waferTab.ChangeSelection( 1 )`?

Comment: Try using `SetSelection` instead. If the GUI is not updated automatically then use `Refresh`

Comment: I know that is actually looping through it because when the GUI actually pops up it displays the last tab like it should but im unable to see the program actually going through the tabs all

Comment: Try `wx.SafeYield` between `Refresh` and `time.sleep` so the GUI has a chance for updating.

Comment: I edited my original post trying to do what you suggested not sure if that's what you meant @Ripi2

Comment: `time.sleep` may terminate early (see [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html)). So if you want to see slow page-next page changes use a `wx.Timer` and react at each timer fire.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you would want to do this as it seems like a confusing interface for a user to use, but here's an example using a `wx.Timer`:

```
import random
import wx


class TabPanel(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        """"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent)

        colors = ["red", "blue", "gray", "yellow", "green"]
        self.SetBackgroundColour(random.choice(colors))

        btn = wx.Button(self, label="Press Me")
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(btn, 0, wx.ALL, 10)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)


class DemoFrame(wx.Frame):
    """
    Frame that holds all other widgets
    """

    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""        
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, 
                          "Notebook Tutorial",
                          size=(600,400)
                          )
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.timer = wx.Timer(self)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.change_tabs, self.timer)
        self.timer.Start(1000)

        self.notebook = wx.Notebook(panel)
        tabOne = TabPanel(self.notebook)
        self.notebook.AddPage(tabOne, "Tab 1")

        tabTwo = TabPanel(self.notebook)
        self.notebook.AddPage(tabTwo, "Tab 2")

        tabThree = TabPanel(self.notebook)
        self.notebook.AddPage(tabThree, 'Tab 3')

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.notebook, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.Layout()

        self.Show()

    def change_tabs(self, event):
        current_selection = self.notebook.GetSelection()
        print(current_selection)
        pages = self.notebook.GetPageCount()
        if current_selection + 1 == pages:
            self.notebook.ChangeSelection(0)
        else:
            self.notebook.ChangeSelection(current_selection + 1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(True)
    frame = DemoFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

You could also use a Thread and use something like `wx.CallAfter` to update your UI, but I think a timer makes more sense in this case.